# Mixed and random effect model with multiple crossed random effects in lme4 vs nlme

Tags: lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I am trying to fit a few models as follows for my data of observations recorded from $p$ genotypes planted in $n$ locations for $m$ years. The aim is to estimate BLUPs finally.

$$Y_{ijk} = \mu + G_i + L_j + T_k + R(T_k*L_j) + GL_{ij} + GT_{ik} + \epsilon_{ijk} $$

$Y_{ijk}:$ Observed variable

$\mu:$ Overall mean

$G_i:$ $i$th Genotype effect

$L_j:$ $j$th Location effect

$T_k:$ $k$th year effect

$R(T_k \times L_k):$ Effect of replicate within (Year $\times$ Location)

$GL_{ij}:$ Effect of Genotype $\times$ Location interaction

$GT_{ik}:$ Effect of Genotype $\times$ Year interaction

$\epsilon_{ijk}:$ Resiual error

Consider that all the $p$ genotypes are present in all the $n$ locations and all the $m$ years.

I am able to use `lme4` syntax as follows.

For model with all effects as random

```
lmer(Trait ~ (1|Genotype) + (1|Location) + (1|Year) + (1|Replication%in%Location:Year) + (1|Genotype:Location) + (1|Genotype:Year), data = data1)
```

For model with all effects as except Year as fixed

```
lmer(Trait ~ (1|Genotype) + (1|Location) + Year + (1|Replication%in%Location:Year) + (1|Genotype:Location) + (1|Genotype:Year), data = data1)
```

For a model with an 3 way interaction term $GLT_{ijk}$ added

$$Y_{ijk} = \mu + G_i + L_j + T_k + R(T_k*L_j) + GL_{ij} + GT_{ik} + GLT_{ijk} + \epsilon_{ijk}$$

$GLT_{ijk}:$ Effect of Genotype $\times$ Location $\times$ Year interaction

```
lmer(Trait ~ (1|Genotype) + (1|Location) + Year + (1|Replication%in%Location:Year) + (1|Genotype:Location) + (1|Genotype:Year) + (1|Genotype:Location:Year), data = data1)
```

As I am getting zero variance for a few observed variables using `lme4`, I am not able to estimate the BLUPs ( all are zero in `ranef()`). I am now trying to do the same with `nlme` package.

**1.** What is the syntax for the above in `nlme`? I struggling with `pdBlocked` and `pdIdent` parameters.

**2.** Will the same syntax hold good for an unbalanced design, i.e. when all the $p$ genotypes are not present in all the $n$ locations and all the $m$ years?

Comment: What makes you think that using 'nlme' would give you non-zero estimates for those variance components if you were to fit the same model?

Comment: @Wolfgang Because of this [Variance estimate at 0 with lmer - not with lme - issue or rounding ?](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q2/018397.html). If they are zero, I can't estimate the BLUPs which I need for comparison.

Comment: If you think that the almost-zero variances given by `nlme` are going to be more reliable than the exactly-zero variances given by `lme4` I'm a little concerned about your analysis.  You could use `blme` to force non-zero variances, but you should be thinking hard about what you're doing ...

Comment: @Crops So, using ``lme`` will give you an estimate that is artificially larger than zero by an amount that is basically below machine precision in the first place. Then you will extract BLUPs that will vary almost imperceptibly but to which you attach some deeper meaning. You think that makes sense?

Comment: @Crops: just want to point out that I'm not trying to be harsh, and I don't think Wolfgang is either, but we're worried (or at least I am) that what you're trying to do doesn't make sense, so it's hard to answer the question as posed.

Comment: @BenBolker I am trying to make sense of the model again keeping in mind your suggestions. Now I think the question is why do I get zero random effect variance for genotypes. If i remove the nested factor from the model, I am not getting the zero variance and can estimate the BLUPs. Is the model "over-parametrized"?

Comment: PS: I had been following the procedure in [this link](http://www.extension.org/pages/61006/estimating-heritability-and-blups-for-traits-using-tomato-phenotypic-data#.VCz2PVeiJ31). Withe their sample data, I am not getting the zero variance. But with my data, I am getting zero variance of random effects.

Comment: Is it because the number of levels in Location and Year are 2 while that in replicate within (Year × Location) is 1.

Comment: I have the similar kind of dataset.But the code doesn't work when I introduce this particular one (1|Replication%in%Location:Year). It gives an "error:grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level" But it works when I give the code as (1+Replication/Location:Year). Does both the codes mean the same? Thank you